# Javascript - table within scrolling div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

So I've got a table within a scrolling div. Right now, I resize the div every time the window is resized to allow the user to see as much of the table as possible.

```
function resizeTable() {
    document.getElementById('table-container').style.height = 
        (window.innerHeight-60)+'px';
};
```

The only issue is that sometimes the table height becomes smaller than the encompassing div so I get some wasted space at the bottom. So what I would like to have is for the div to resize to the window height *unless* the height of the table is less than the window height. I've tried this...

```
function resizeTable() {
    var tableContainer = document.getElementById('table-container');
    var table = tableContainer.childNodes[0];
    if (table.offsetHeight < (window.innerHeight-60)) 
        { tableContainer.style.height = table.offsetHeight; }
    else 
        { tableContainer.style.height = (window.innerHeight-60)+'px'; }
};
```

...but it doesn't work right and cuts off more and more of the table as the window is resized over time. So I come to you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `style.maxHeight` instead of `style.height`.